# how to solve : foreach statement cannot operate

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a controller called "BookController" :

```
public ActionResult Book(int? id)
    {

        var result = db.Books.Where(b => b.Book_id == id).Single();
        var user = db.AspNetUsers.Where(b => b.Id == result.User_ID).Single();
        ViewBag.User_ID = user.UserName;
        return View(result);
    }

public ActionResult SameAuthor(string author)
        {

            var result = db.Books.Where(b => b.Author_name == author).Take(4);
             return View(result.ToList());
        }
```

also this is the view code "books.cshtml" :

```
@model SmartBookLibrary.Models.Book
@using SmartBookLibrary.Controllers
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Book_name;
    BookController book = new BookController();
    var auth = Model.Author_name;
}
@section AdditionalMeta
{
<link href="~/Content/blog-post.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <!-- Blog Post Content Column -->
        <div class="col-lg-8">

            <!-- Blog Post -->
            <!-- Title -->
            <h1>@Model.Book_name (@Model.Edition th Edition)  <a href="~/Admin/books/edit/@Model.Book_id"><small class="fa fa-edit"></small></a></h1>

            <!-- Author -->
            <p class="lead">
                by <a href="#">@ViewBag.User_ID</a>
            </p>

            <hr>

            <!-- Date/Time -->
            <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> Posted on @Model.Publish_date</p>

            <hr>

            <!-- Preview Image -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <img class="img-show" src="/Books/RetrieveImage/@Model.Book_id" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-1">
                    <dl>Book Name : @Model.Book_name</dl>
                    <dl>Book Edition : @Model.Edition</dl>
                    <dl>Author Name : @Model.Author_name</dl>
                    <dl>Category : @Model.Category.Category_name</dl>
                    <dl>Book Name: @Model.Book_name</dl>
                    <dl>ISN : 2015</dl>
                </div>
            </div>                    

            <hr>

            <!-- Post Content -->

            <p class="lead">@Html.Raw(Model.Book_Description)</p>



            <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">
                Download @Model.Book_name
                <i class="fa fa-cloud-download"></i>
            </button>     




            <hr>
            <div class="well">
                <div class="row">
                    @*   I Want to call the contoller method , it will return 4 post , then i want to show them here   *@
                    @{
                        var b = book.SameAuthor(auth);
                        foreach (var cat in b)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="/Books/RetrieveImage/" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                                </div>

                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Book_name</h3>
                                    <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>

                                    <p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                                            Button
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
                                            Button
                                        </a>
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }


                </div>

            </div>
            <hr>
            <!-- Blog Comments -->
            <!-- Comments Form -->
            <div class="well">
                <h4>Leave a Comment:</h4>
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>

            <hr>

            <!-- Posted Comments -->
            <!-- Comment -->
            <div class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                    <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                        Start Bootstrap
                        <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                    </h4>
                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Comment -->
            <div class="media">
                <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                    <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                </a>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading">
                        Start Bootstrap
                        <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                    </h4>
                    Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                    <!-- Nested Comment -->
                    <div class="media">
                        <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/64x64" alt="">
                        </a>
                        <div class="media-body">
                            <h4 class="media-heading">
                                Nested Start Bootstrap
                                <small>August 25, 2014 at 9:30 PM</small>
                            </h4>
                            Cras sit amet nibh libero, in gravida nulla. Nulla vel metus scelerisque ante sollicitudin commodo. Cras purus odio, vestibulum in vulputate at, tempus viverra turpis. Fusce condimentum nunc ac nisi vulputate fringilla. Donec lacinia congue felis in faucibus.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Nested Comment -->
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Blog Sidebar Widgets Column -->
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <!-- Blog Search Well -->
            <div class="well">
                <h4>Search</h4>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                        </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                <!-- /.input-group -->
            </div>

            <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
            <div class="well">
                <h4>Blog Categories</h4>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category Name</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category Name</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category Name</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category Name</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category Name</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category Name</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category Name</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Category Name</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.row -->
            </div>

            <!-- Side Widget Well -->
            <div class="well">
                <h4>Books May You Interest</h4>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

my problem actually here in this code "in books.cshtml":

```
 @{
                        var b = book.SameAuthor(auth);
                        foreach (var cat in b)
                        {
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <img src="/Books/RetrieveImage/" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                                </div>

                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h3>Book_name</h3>
                                    <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>

                                    <p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                                            Button
                                        </a>

                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
                                            Button
                                        </a>
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    }
```

The Error i got is :

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1579  foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' because 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'  SmartBookLibrary    C:\Users\Firas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SmartBookLibrary\SmartBookLibrary\Views\Book\Book.cshtml   73  Active
```

Note : I Tried to change the model type to this :

```
@model IEnumerable <SmartBookLibrary.Models.Book>
```

and the error is gone , but i got error for all the view code (any code start with @model) , and this is a sample of error i got:

```
    Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IEnumerable<Book>' does not contain a definition for 'Book_name' and no extension method 'Book_name' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<Book>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   SmartBookLibrary    C:\Users\Firas\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\SmartBookLibrary\SmartBookLibrary\Views\Book\Book.cshtml   4   Active
```

can any one help me with a solution ! and thanks

Comment: `SameAuthor` why are you returning a view??

Answer (score 1):

The error is self explanatory. `SameAuthor()` action method returns an `ActionResult` type. You cannot loop through that !

Looks like your `SameAuthor` action method returns a view (markup) with the data you wanted. So why not just include that in the main view with Html.Action helper method

```
@Html.Action("SameAuthor", Model.Author_name)
```

**Or** you should create a view model for your view which has the details of one book and the a collection of books for "Books from the same author".

```
public class BooksDetailsVm
{
    public Book Book { set;get;}
    public List<Book> BooksFromSameAuthor { set;get;}
}
```

and in your GET action, load this data

```
public ActionResult Book(int? id)
{
    if (id != null)
    {
        var vm = new BooksDetailsVm();
        var b = db.Books.Where(O => O.Book_id == id).Single();
        vm.Book = b;
        var user = db.AspNetUsers.Where(P => P.Id == b.User_ID).Single();
        vm.BooksFromSameAuthor = db.Books.Where(t => t.Author_name == b.Author_name).Take(4).ToList();
        ViewBag.User_ID = user.UserName;
        return View(vm);
    }
    return HttpNotFound();
}
```

And your view, which is strongly typed to our new BookDetailsVm

```
@model BookDetailsVm
<h1>@Model.Book.Name</h1>
<h4>Books from same author</h4>
@foreach(var item in Model.BooksFromSameAuthor)
{
    <p>@item.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks , I'm sure that is very helpful , but can you please expain to me how to use @Html.Action("SameAuthor",Model.Author_name)
 in my code , because actually it's the first time i'm using this method and i have no idea, or if you have an example or if you can show me my code with this helper method , thanks ..

Comment: Why don't you just include that simply line in your main view ( and remove those foreach where you have the bad code) ?

Comment: Ok , i'll try , it's just because i'm still learning , sorry and i'll let you know what i get .

Comment: Hello , i used it and got this error :
An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Execution of the child request failed. Please examine the InnerException for more information.

Comment: That means your code is crashing while trying to execute that action method. Try to access it directly like `/yourController/SameAuthor?author=somenamehere` and you will be able to see the error. Put visual studio breakpoints as needed to debug.

Comment: please have a look on this , may you understood me , i know that i have a weak skills :
http://i.imgur.com/KmFeUfp.png ........... http://i.imgur.com/o44cwhe.png

Comment: Did you try what i said ? Accessing the SameAuthor action in a browser?  also, **The first lesson of debugging is** , When you get an error from a massive amount of code (which you are not sure what for), Comment out everything, Run. If the error went away ,Un comment some code and repeat the same process until you get the error. With this you will be able to understand which part is failing.

Comment: i tried the debugging via url : always got error on this method :
Line 18:             var result = db.Books.Where(b => b.Book_id == id).Single();

Comment: i've no enough point to chat with you , but please if you can help me with that i appreciate that so much , this project i should send it on 15'th of this month and i still have a lot of views i should create as same view i have this error with , so please if you can help me with solve this problem i'll help and improve my skills in the coming views i should create and thanks .

Comment: Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: That means your where clause is not returning a single item. Are you sure you have a record with Book_id value=id ?

Comment: Yes , I'm sure , if i don't have a record , so it will not from the start view the book details , but what i'm trying to do is to display a simple block under the book details with 4 books for same author , Sir , do you have a facebook , twiter , skype , anything , please maybe it's not correct to go away from here , but i really tired and trying since week ago in same problem and i know it's solvable but maybe if you have a look on my code will be more easy for you

Comment: The answer i provided (using a view model) should give you the 4 books from the same answer.

Comment: i tried your viewmodel answer also , i got same error :  
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: I added a null checking in the updates answer. did you try that ?

Comment: then when i click continue it show the post details only , with only 1 / 4 sameauthor details and no image

Comment: Sir your ViewModel answer is works , but i got on each time i reload or open any book detail page this error , then i click continue and it's show the content + sameauthor books : An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no elements

Comment: which line are you getting that error ? what code is in that line ?

Comment: Ok , to be clear with you and explain it exactly , i'll post steps in few comments .

Comment: 1- i closed the application and run it again .

Comment: 2- got this error : An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: line 21 :             var b = db.Books.Where(O => O.Book_id == id).Single();

Comment: That is not the code in my answer ! You need to sit back and read the updated answer again.

Comment: then i clicked continue , and everything working well , so how we can solve this problem and thanks , actually you did a great job and i wish to finish it

Comment: Did you even read my last comment. I added null checking in the updated answer. Try that. If you get a string "Book not found for the Id passed" , It means there is no record for the id you passed in the table !

Comment: and it's work , i did it before i see your comment , i tried and saw ur comment in code , then i added a null checking , so solved !!! thanks Sir , and i appreciate that .

Comment: Thanks for help brother :)